# How to authenticate to a remote db host with MongoKit?

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, pymongo, mongokit

I am attempting to connect and authenticate to a remote database host (dotcloud, mongolabs, etc) using MongoKit within Flask. Connecting to the server seems to work fine. However I am unable to authenticate to the database. Presumably this should work:

```
from mongokit import Connection
connection = Connection(my_remote_host, my_remote_port)
connection.my_database.authenticate(my_admin_user, my_admin_password)
```

the call to authenticate() returns True, yet subsequent calls to fetch data throw:

```
OperationFailure: database error: unauthorized db
```

Anyone know what might be happening here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is likely due to the current behavior of `authenticate()` in pymongo. Pymongo doesn't cache authentication credentials between threads, so each thread must authenticate individually. See the [note in the pymongo documentation](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/database.html#pymongo.database.Database.authenticate) about using `authenticate()` in a multi-threaded environment.

Comment: PyMongo handles authentication across threads since version 2.0: http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/changelog.html#changes-in-version-2-0